# CheckDb job is failing in our Server , could any one please solution on this

Tags: sql-server-2008

In one of our server checkDB is failing in 2008 SQL server, I tried to fix the issue.

Can anyone please provide the solution without data loss.
Thanks a TON

Error Message:-    Message

> Executed as user: XXXX. Date and time: 2019-12-01 04:26:31  Server: XXXX  Version: 10.0.2531.0  Edition: Enterprise Edition (64-bit)  Procedure: [Admin].[dbo].[DatabaseIntegrityCheck]  Parameters: @Databases = 'XXXx', @CheckCommands = 'CHECKDB', @PhysicalOnly = 'N', @NoIndex = 'N', @ExtendedLogicalChecks = 'N', @TabLock = 'N', @FileGroups = NULL, @Objects = NULL, @MaxDOP = NULL, @AvailabilityGroups = NULL, @AvailabilityGroupReplicas = 'ALL', @Updateability = 'ALL', @LockTimeout = NULL, @LogToTable = 'Y', @Execute = 'Y'  Source: https://ola.hallengren.com [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)  Date and time: 2019-12-01 04:26:31  Database: [XXXX]  Status: ONLINE  Standby: No  Updateability: READ_WRITE  User access: MULTI_USER  Is accessible: Yes  Recovery model: FULL [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)  Date and time: 2019-12-01 04:26:31  Command: DBCC CHECKDB ([XXXX]) WITH NO_INFOMSGS, ALL_ERRORMSGS, DATA_PURITY [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)  Check Catalog Msg 3853, State 1: Attribute (object_id=871010184) of row (object_id=871010184,column_id=1) in sys.columns does not have a matching row (object_id=871010184) in sys.objects. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 8992)  Check Catalog Msg 3853, State 1: Attribute (object_id=871010184) of row (object_id=871010184,column_id=2) in sys.columns does not have a matching row (object_id=871010184) in sys.objects. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 8992)  Check Catalog Msg 3853, State 1: Attribute (object_id=871010184) of row (object_id=871010184,column_id=3) in sys.columns does not have a matching row (object_id=871010184) in sys.objects. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 8992)  The Index Allocation Map (IAM) page (0:0) is pointed to by the previous pointer of IAM page (1:7816) in object ID 0, index ID -1, partition ID 0, alloc unit ID 338557500129280 (type Unknown), but it was not detected in the scan. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 2576)  CHECKDB found 1 allocation errors and 3 consistency errors not associated with any single object. [SQLSTATE 01000] (Error 8954)  CHECKDB found 1 allocation errors and 3 consistency errors in database 'XXX'. [SQLSTATE 01000] (Error 8989).  The step failed.

Comment: The question may be better located on Server Fault.  I'd suggest posting it there instead.  SO is primarily for questions whose primary focus is programming.

Comment: I think no one know the  solution